# Custom filter for the array adapter in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, filter, adapter

```
public class SpotAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Spot> {

    private ArrayList<Spot> mFilteredList, mUnfilteredList;
    private Filter mFilter;

    public SpotAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Spot> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        mUnfilteredList = (ArrayList<Spot>) items;
        mFilteredList = (ArrayList<Spot>) items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v =  vi.inflate(R.layout.record_row, null);
        }

        Spot p = (Spot) mFilteredList.get(position);

        if (p != null) {
            TextView nameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView addressView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.address);
            TextView typeView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.type);
            TextView contactView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact);
            ImageView starBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.star);

            contactView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nameView.setText(p.name);
            addressView.setText(p.address);
            typeView.setText(p.type == 1 ? "Leisure" : "Shopping");
            starBtn.setTag("" + p.id);
            starBtn.setVisibility(p.isStar ? View.VISIBLE :  View.GONE);
        }

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new Filter() {

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    mFilteredList = (ArrayList<Spot>)results.values;
                    clear();
                    int count = mFilteredList.size();
                    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
                    {
                        Spot s = (Spot)mFilteredList.get(i);
                        add(s);
                    }
//                  
//                  mFilteredList = (ArrayList<Spot>)results.values;
//                  notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    Log.d("test1","c "+constraint);
                    Log.d("test1","s "+mUnfilteredList.size());

                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    ArrayList<Spot> newList = new ArrayList<Spot>();              
                    for (Spot obj : mUnfilteredList) {
                        // Compare the custom object and add to list if match
                        if (constraint.equals("bookmark")) {  
                            if (obj.isStar == true)
                                newList.add(obj); 
                        } else if (constraint.equals("select all")) {
                            newList.add(obj);
                        }
                    }

                    Log.d("test1",""+newList.size());
                    results.values = newList;
                    results.count = newList.size();
                    return results;
                }
            };
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

}
```

The above is the custom filter , my idea is there is two filter option "bookMark" / "select all", that means select all show original list while the bookMark show bookmark item only.

The problem is , if I click on bookmark , then I click on select all ,  the result is still the bookmark item.

So I log the result, I found that in the second time the `mUnfilteredList = (ArrayList<Spot>) items;` will rerun so **the unfiltered list is only the last filter result instead of keeping the original list**. How can I change to fix the problem?

Thanks for helping

Comment: what are you doing when you click on "bookmark" ? is your adapter connected to AutoCompleteTextView ? do you call your filter directly?

Comment: call filter directly, like this sAdapter.getFilter().filter("select all"); sAdapter.getFilter().filter("bookmark");

Comment: seem you should create two adapters then

Comment: Why the mUnfilteredList is affected? I try to log at the constructor but it only run the mUnfilteredList = (ArrayList<Spot>) items; 1 time , so it should not change , thanks

Comment: the clear() has clean all data .

Comment: my guess is that mUnfilteredList =
(ArrayList<Spot>) items; is wrong, it shouldnt point to items but co items copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mFilteredList  = new ArrayList(items);

Comment: mFilteredList or mUnfilteredList ?

Comment: both need to be new ArrayList(items)

Comment: ok, so i would suggest to create two adapters since now you have three copies of your data which in large datasets can be an issue